# Scheduler is not initialized when the Google Guice application is launched. Java

Tags: java, hibernate, guice

Help me please, such situation. Hibernate + Google Guice frameworks.
Added a scheduler, set the execution time every 10 seconds (for the test) to call the searchFile () method in which the folder is checked for files, if the folder is not empty, then we call the parser and the parse file and using the service - dao - write to the database. (PostgreSQL)

When you start the application, the scheduler is not called.

My class looks like this: interface **SchedulerTask**:

```
       import com.google.inject.ImplementedBy;

@ImplementedBy(SchedulerTaskBean.class)
public interface SchedulerTask {

    void startSchedulerTask();

    void searchFile();
}
```

Its implementation **(SchedulerTaskBean):**

```
    import com.google.inject.Inject;
import com.google.inject.Singleton;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@Singleton
public class SchedulerTaskBean implements Job, SchedulerTask {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(SchedulerTaskBean.class);

    @Inject
    private SchedulerTask schedulerTask;
    @Inject
    private CsvService csvService;

    @Override
    public void startSchedulerTask() {
        ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(this::searchFile, 0,  10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
//        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(folder::searchFile, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        searchFile();
    }

    public SchedulerTaskBean() {
        startSchedulerTask();
    }

    @Override
    public void searchFile() {
        Parser parser = new CsvParserFromLib();

        File dir = new File("/home/prog5/Documents/test/");
        // если объект представляет каталог
        if (dir.isDirectory()) {
            File[] listFiles= dir.listFiles();
            // Если папка не пустая - парсим что там есть, и переносим спаршеный файл в другую папку, чтоб второй раз его не спарсить.
            if(listFiles != null && listFiles.length>0){
                for (File file : listFiles) {
                    List<CsvStructureEntity> listStructure = parser.parse(file);
                    if (listStructure != null) {
                        try {
                            csvService.create(listStructure);
                        } catch (DataNotFoundException e) {
                            LOGGER.error(e);
                        }
                    } else {
                        // todo переместить файл в папку "error"
                        File badFolder = new File("/home/prog5/Documents/test/error");
                        dir.renameTo(badFolder);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        searchFile();
    }
}
```

But if you move

```
    @Inject
private SchedulerTask schedulerTask;
```

in another controller (let's say an authorization controller) and run the application, it starts up and goes into my searchFile () method (to breakpoint) and my service is not null, it works fine.

Help me please how to force Google Guice to initialize my scheduler at application start, not transferring it to other controller? For it to run automatically when the application starts and for example every 12 hours (now indicated 10 seconds for the test) did my method ?

This is my **CsvService:**

```
    @ImplementedBy(CsvServiceBean.class)
public interface CsvService {

    List<CsvStructureEntity> create(List<CsvStructureEntity> csvStructureEntity) throws DataNotFoundException;

}
```

**CsvServiceBean:**

```
    public class CsvServiceBean implements CsvService {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(CsvServiceBean.class);

    @Inject
    private CsvDao csvDao;

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public List<CsvStructureEntity> create(final List<CsvStructureEntity> csvStructureEntity) {
        csvDao.persistAll(csvStructureEntity);
        return csvStructureEntity;
    }
}
```

**CsvDao:**

```
     @ImplementedBy(CsvDaoBean.class)
public interface CsvDao {

    void persistAll(List<CsvStructureEntity> csvStructureEntity);
}
```

**CsvDaoBean:**

```
       public class CsvDaoBean extends ValidatableDaoBean<CsvStructureEntity, Long> implements CsvDao {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(CsvDaoBean.class);

    @Override
    protected Class<CsvStructureEntity> getEntityClass() {
        return CsvStructureEntity.class;
    }
}
```

**ValidatableDaoBean:**

```
    public abstract class ValidatableDaoBean<Entity, Id> extends AbstractJpaDao<Entity, Id> {

    @Override
    public void persist(final Entity entity) {
        validate(entity);
        super.persist(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public Entity merge(final Entity entity) {
        validate(entity);
        return super.merge(entity);
    }

    private void validate(Entity entity) {
        if(entity == null) {
            throw new ValidationException("Object is null.");
        }
        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
        Set<ConstraintViolation<Entity>> violations = validator.validate(entity);
        if(violations.size() > 0) {
            List<String> messages = new ArrayList<>();
            for (ConstraintViolation<Entity> violation : violations) {
                messages.add(violation.getMessage());
            }
            throw new ValidationException(StringUtils.join(messages, ", "));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void persistAll(List<Entity> entities) {
        super.persistAll(entities);
    }
}
```

**Thank you very much in advance!**